# Running a For Loop in VBA on a Selected Range

Tags: vba, for-loop, formatting, range

What I am trying to do is simple but I just can't get it to work. I want select a range of cells and the run a macro that will:

1. Run a for loop from the first row to the last row on the range selected
2. Then return the "=NUMBERVALUE()" of the concatenated values in each column of the row
3. The output column will be right next to the last column of the selected range

This is what I have for the code:

```
Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = Selection

First_Col = myRange.Column
Last_Row = myRange.Rows.Count + myRange.Row - 1
Last_Col = myRange.Column + myRange.Columns.Count - 1
Out_put_Col = Last_Col + 1


For i = myRange.Row To Last_Row

    Cells(i, Out_put_Col) = "=NUMBERVALUE(Cells(i, First_Col) & Cells(i, First_Col+1)"

Next i
```

VBA is having issues with what is written in the for loop. I am newer to VBA but based on the way this is written I would have though it would work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you found the reply helpful, please be sure to "upvote" is and, ideally, "accept" it.

Answer (score 1):

more like:

```
For i = myRange.Row To Last_Row

    Cells(i, Out_put_Col) = "=NUMBERVALUE(" & Cells(i, First_Col).address & ":" & _
                                          Cells(i, First_Col+1).address & ")"

Next i
```

I'm not sure NumberValue works like that though.

Comment: Thank you so much! For what I am trying to do, I needed to change the ":" to "&". But this worked great!